# google pay store upload error: differentiating APK details

Tags: android, apk

Our latest build with Xamarin got blocked by Google. The package name etc. haven't changed and I even can't find this error message on the internet.

Comment: your old app isn't official?

Comment: no, it's closed alpha. We've uploaded five versions so far.

Comment: "differentiating APK details" that is all the error is?

Comment: It appears that you intentionally or accidentally tried to upload multiple APKs for an app. and to upload multiple APKs for same app you need to set filter so that two APKs doesn't completely overlap filter configurations. check [this](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#Rules). the filters are applied to AndroidManifest file.

Comment: Problem solved: In the AndroidManifest.xml the target Android version was set to "Automatic - use target framework version (API 25)". I changed it back to "API level 25" and now the upload was successful. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: In the AndroidManifest.xml the target Android version was set to "Automatic - use target framework version (API 25)". I changed it back to "API level 25" and now the upload was successful. Thanks for the help.